# Javascript - forEach with promise.all not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to handle promises with for each but not working

I assume it will log something because of `console.log(result)`.

Why is it not working?

It only logs

```
All done (54) [ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ]
```

```
          let promises = [];
                  mkt.forEach(async function (marketItem, index) {
                    promises.push(() => {
                      context.program.account.chain
                        .fetch(sth)
                        .then((result) => {
                console.log(result)
                        });
                    });
                  });
          Promise.all(promises)
                    .then(results => {
                      console.log('All done', results);
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                      // Handle errors here
                    });
```

Comment: `.forEach()` + `.push()` -> `.map()`

Comment: You're filling `promises` with _functions_, not promises (and those functions don't even return the promises they create). Also as `forEach` isn't promise-aware, making its callback `async` is pointless (especially as you don't `await` inside it...)

Comment: `.push(context.program.account.chain.fetch(sth))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
let promises = mkt.map((marketItem, index) => {
     return context.program.account.chain.fetch(sth)
 });
Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    console.log('All done', results);
})
.catch(e => {
    // Handle errors here
});
```

Don't push resolved promise, push the promise.